# How to version yaml files making up an API specifications?

Tags: api, yaml, openapi, versioning, specifications

I am working on an API specifications and I am spliting the API into multiple yaml files.
I am using semantic versioning strategy (major.minor.patch). If I need to make a breaking change in one of the files, then I will create a new major version of this file. Should I create a new version of all the other files that I don't need to changed?
If the answer id "no", then I will end up having a certain file with version 2.0.0 referencing another file with version 1.0.0
In this case how can I determine the version of the API specification (made up from those files) I am publishing to the API consumers, will it be 1 or 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your API spec is a *set of files*, as you wrote, then

**full set of schemes** must be tagged with "new version" regardless of revisions and state (changed|unchanged) of every single file. Period